# Angular $resource data is available to view but not in the code

Tags: javascript, php, html, angularjs, google-maps

I'm an angular noob and am really frustrated with a particular problem.

I have a $resource returning data from the server, which contains key/value pairs i.e.  detail.name, detail.email etc.

I can access this information on the view using `{{detail.name}}` notation, but I cannot access it in the code, which is driving me nuts, as I need this data to do stuff with.

How can I access it in the backend?

here's the code generating the data:

```
mydata = Appointment.get({id: $stateParams.id}, function(data){
    geocoder.geocode(data);
    $scope.detail = data;
});
```

on the view I have the following:

```
<address class="text-left"> 
                {{detail.address_1}}</br>
                {{detail.city}}</br>
                {{detail.postcode}}</br>
                </address>
        </hr>       
        <p> {{detail.lat}}</p>
        <p> {{detail.lng}}</p>
        <p> {{center}}</p>
```

this is all ok.

however, if I add `console.log($scope.detail.lat)` in the $resource callback i get undefined.

Here is the resource definition:

```
angular.module('MyApp')
.factory('Appointment', function($resource){
    return $resource('/api/admin/:id', { id: "@_id" }, {
         query: {method:'GET', isArray:true}, 
         update: { method:'PUT' }
    });
})
```

and the geocoder factory if anyone is interested:

```
angular.module('MyApp')
.factory('geocoder', ['$http','$state', function($http, $state){

var geocoder ={};

geocoder.geocode = function (formData){
    var myformData = {};
    var address = formData.address_1+', '+formData.city+', '+formData.postcode;

                var key = 'AIzaSyACVwB4i_6ujTrdjTMI-_tnsDrf6yOfssw';

                $http.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='+address+'&key='+key).
                  success(function(results, status, headers, config) {
                    var results = results.results[0];
                    formData.lat = results.geometry.location.lat;
                    formData.lng = results.geometry.location.lng;
                        myformData = formData;
                    return myformData;          

                     // this callback will be called asynchronously
                    // when the response is available
                  }).
                  error(function(results, status, headers, config) {
                    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
                    // or server returns response with an error status.
                  });   
}


return geocoder;

}])
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: geocoder factory is set up all wrong....should be returning the `$http` promise and using a promise resolve `then()` to set the data. Really need to understand what `asynchronous` means and deeply study the link I provided in your last question

Answer (score 0):

You could do utilize the promise return from the `$resource` object & then utilize that promise in controller.

**Factory**

```
angular.module('MyApp')
.factory('Appointment', function($resource){
    return $resource('/api/admin/:id', { id: "@_id" }, {
         query: {method:'GET', isArray:true}, 
         update: { method:'PUT' }
    });
})
```

**Controller**

```
mydata = Appointment.get({id: $stateParams.id}).$promise;
mydata.then(function(data){
    geocoder.geocode(data);
    $scope.detail = data;
});
```